# How to store a Superscript value manually in MySQL using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to manually enter some formulas in my database using phpMyAdmin using its GUI. Please note that I am NOT USING any php script to store the result. I just want to enter it MANUALLY. The formulas contain use of subscript and superscript (x<sup>2</sup> and x<sub>2</sub>). if I try to copy and paste a formula, it shows x2 instead of x<sup>2</sup> and x<sub>2</sub>.

Current Setting of the column in which I want to enter the data is utf8_unicode_ci.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode contains code points for superscript numerals

U+2070 - U+2079 is the code point range. Not every font has glyphs for these characters, but many do. See this for example:  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2070/index.htm

If you can figure out how to type these Unicode characters into your web browser, you'll be able to get phpMyAdmin to insert them into your utf8 varchar() columns. The typing of unicode characters is browser specific.

Comment: This is the best answer to the question, but the ultimate solution is that you shouldn't be storing formulae in plain text in your database. You'll be much happier in the end if you use a markup language (LaTeX or MathML are probably the two standard choices AFAIK). For instance, how do you indicate summation ∑ or the radical sign?